# $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that given prime set $X= \{p_1,p_2,,..,p_a\}$, $p_1p_2...p_a - nk$ cannot be decomposed into $a$ prime factors in $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

How does one find minimum $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that given prime set $X= \{p_1,p_2,,..,p_a\}$ and $X \subset \mathbb{N}$,

$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{a}p_i - nk$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be decomposed into $a$ prime factors in $X$ except when $n = 0$, allowing same prime factor to be used more than once? [For example, $2^2$ is considered to have two prime factors, 2 used twice.]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? Are you looking for something other than the obvious straightforward method of checking for $k=1$, $k=2$, etc.? What limitations do you place on the desired algorithm?

Comment: Obviously, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't make sense, at least for those $n=q\cdot \prod_{i=1}^{a}p_i$, $q \in \mathbb{Z}$